# Extract value from string using a predefined string keyholder

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have the following `Array` of `strings`:

```
array = [
   "My Website | :PrismicReplace|title"
   "My Website | Contact Us"
];
```

I want to loop over these arrays, and if the element contains `:PrismicReplace` I want to extract the value after the pipe, such that `:PrismicReplace|title` within the string returns back `title` as the key...

i.e.,

```
>> my_function("My Website | :PrismicReplace|title")
title
```

The string could be:

`"My Website | :PrismicReplace|someReallyReallyReallyLongParameter"`

(returns someReallyReallyReallyLongParameter)

or

`"My Website | :PrismicReplace|someReallyReallyReallyLongParameter Some Other Stuff"`

(still returns someReallyReallyReallyLongParameter)

I've tried a combination of loops, and regex matches, but it's not quite working yet as I intended to...but I'm thinking and hoping there is a quick way around this? The best I have so far is this:

```
    if (new RegExp(':PrismicReplace').test(tagDef.content)) {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(prismic)) {
        let paramRegex = new RegExp(`:PrismicReplace|${key}`);
        if (paramRegex.test(tagDef.content)) {
          tagDef.content = tagDef.content.replace(paramRegex, prismic[key]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capturing group for the part after the pipe.

```
:PrismicReplace\|([^\s|]+)
```

In parts

- `:PrismicReplace\|` Match `:PrismicReplace|`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s|]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except a pipe or whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WIgZyN/1)

```js
let array = [
  "My Website | :PrismicReplace|title",
  "My Website | Contact Us",
  "My Website | :PrismicReplace|someReallyReallyReallyLongParameter",
  "My Website | :PrismicReplace|someReallyReallyReallyLongParameter Some Other Stuff"
];
const regex = /:PrismicReplace\|([^\s|]+)/g;
array.forEach(str => {
  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
});
```